# cannot get the cid of the model while rendering a backbone collection over a template

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, mustache

I am trying to render a backbone collection on a template that is built with mustache.js . The problem is I couldn't get the cid of the model in the template. My code is

```
        <div class="phone span4">
            <h5> Phone Appointments</h5>
            {{ _.each(slots, function(slot) { }}
                {{ if(slot.aptType == "P"){ }}
                    <h6 cid="{{=slot.cid}}"  aptId="{{=slot.aptId}}"> {{=slot.beginTime}}  - {{=slot.endTime}} </h6>
                {{  }   }}
            {{  }); }}
        </div>
```

from the above code, I can get the aptId, beginTime and end Time, but not the Cid. How to get the Cid of the model from a collection while rendering it on a template?

and my render method from the view looks like this

```
    render:function(){
    var template = _.template($("#slot-display-template").html());
    compiledTmp = template({slots: this.collection.toJSON()})
    this.$el.append(compiledTmp);
    }
```

Also is there any disadvantage of using cid as the unique identifier of a model ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Why do you need the cid to be in the html? If you have the model's id (looks like aptId is the idAttribute?), you can find it in the collection, `collection.get(modelId)`.

Answer (score 23):

The `cid` is not included by default in the `toJSON` output. You will need to override `toJSON` in your model definition and include `cid`.

```
toJSON: function() {
  var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.apply(this, arguments);
  json.cid = this.cid;
  return json;
}
```

Comment: In any case is quite weird that there isn't a native way (a flag?) to show "cid" inside the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an ad hock solution, This would work also:

```
var params = _.extend({}, this.model.toJSON(), {cid: this.model.cid})
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way if you don't need to extend behavior of all models you can just add `cid` to your model using `parse` method. For example you have collection 'Collection'. You can specify model for this collection and override `parse` method to attach model's `cid` to the response.

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model
});

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        response.cid = this.cid;
        return response;
    }
});
```

So you'll be able to get `cid` from model's attributes.